# Missing HTTPOnly Cookies at HTTP Request from child iFrame or pop-up window

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, httponly, cookie-httponly

#### Browser (Chrome) doesn't set HttpOnly cookies from child iframe  or pop-up window

I have a parent webpage with a child iframe:

```
Parent at https://sub1.some-domain.com
Child at <iframe src="https://sub2.some-domain.com"> (inside of parent)
```

From Parent I do **POST** request to the API `https://api.some-domain.com`.
Below is the Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sub1.some-domain.com
Set-Cookie:
 payload-name=payload-value;
 max-age=30;
 domain=some-domain.com;
 path=/;
 secure;
 samesite=none;
 httponly
```

Afterwards,
from the Iframe I do **GET** request to "https://api.some-domain.com".
**Expectation:** Browser to include Httponly cookies `payload-name=payload-value;` into the request.

**Result:** Httplonly cookies not included for unknown reason.
**BTW**, I included "*withCredentials*" property into JS Http request, so this couldn't be a problem.

**Update**

*GET Request:*

```
fetch("https://api.some-domain.com/...", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,uk;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"115\", \"Chromium\";v=\"115\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site"
  },
  "referrer": "https://sub2.some-domain.com/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

*GET Response headers:*

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sub2.some-domain.com
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
```

**Update2** 
Locally, everything works fine, httponly cookies included. 
I believe this reason is that `https://api.some-domain.com`, `https://sub1.some-domain.com`, `https://sub2.some-domain.com` is `https://localhost`. 
**Update3** 
The same is issue is when instead of iframe is pop-up window.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://api.some-domain.com`
Isn't this header wrong. 
this should be
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sub2.some-domain.com`

Comment: Oh Sorry, I replaced in text editor real url with fake incorrectly. In the real response it is https://sub2.some-domain.com. I 'll update question

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest cookie behaviours and restrictions are explained in recent updates to the [RFC6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/) document. There have been updates in recent years to both browsers and servers, to prevent unwelcome cross site user tracking.

**SAME SITE**

All of the subdomains you are using share the same parent domain of `some-domain.com`. Assuming that this is not a shared domain from a hosting provider, and that you own the whole domain, this means all requests are in the `same site` and should not be impacted by cookie restrictions. Section 5.2 describes the algorithm.

If the browser domain and the API domain are not in the same site, then cookies will be treated as third party and dropped aggressively, especially on iframe and Ajax requests, where the user is not informed of the origin making the API request.

**CROSS ORIGIN**

Requests from the first two of these domains to the API will be `cross origin` and same site, since in both cases the hostname of the API and browser document is not the same. Therefore cross origin requests will trigger CORS pre-flight OPTIONS requests, which you seem to be dealing with correctly.

```
sub1.some-domain.com
sub2.some-domain.com
api.some-domain.com
```

Since you are calling the API from two web origins, make sure the CORS response headers returned for pre-flight OPTIONS requests vary by origin. I suspect that is already the case though:

```
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

**COOKIE DETAILS**

If you are using authentication cookies to secure requests from the browser to APIs, then I would recommend against using `SameSite=None`. This is intended only for special cases, notably third party cookies issued by authorization servers and identity providers. This prevents cookies used for logins on a top level window from being dropped. I would recommend updating your scenario to use cookie details like this:

```
Set-Cookie:
 payload-name=payload-value;
 max-age=30;
 domain=api.some-domain.com;
 path=/;
 secure;
 samesite=strict;
 httponly
```

The `strict` setting provides the strongest protection against cross site request forgery, unlike the `none` setting. This also ensures that cookies are only sent to the API side of the architecture. If you are using API driven cookies in the browser, you should not need to use the cookie for web requests, if you are just getting static content. In some deployment scenarios, such as when getting web content from a content delivery network, it is more secure to avoid sending an API credential there.

**FIRST PARTY IFRAMES**

Assuming a same site setup, the iframe document for `sub2.some-domain.com` and the main window's top level origin of `sub1.some-domain.com` will be considered to have the same `site for cookies`. The iframe will send an origin of `https://sub2.some-domain.com` to the API and shared cookies work OK.

Use of first party iframes still has some limitations though. If you ever wanted to trigger an OAuth based login from an iframe, eg to sign in via Google, that would not work since the login cookies would be considered third party and dropped.

**THIRD PARTY IFRAMES**

If the same site requirement is not met, then cookies will be dropped by browsers and you won't be able to influence that. Third party iframes that use cookies therefore need to be migrated to first party iframes. This typically involves hosting the iframe in your own web domain, then routing API requests via an API domain in the same site as the web origin.

**FETCH REQUESTS**

Make sure that both POST request with "Set-Credentials: .."  header and next GET request has **"withCredentials" option**.
If POST request would not have it, the cookies wouldn't be set, even if you see them in DEV Tools.

Simplify your FETCH request, since request headers add complexity. Any [non safe headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) you send must have been first requested in a pre-flight OPTIONS request, resulting in response headers like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
```

Simplify it something like this. Mostly the browser code only needs to opt into sending cross origin cookies. You should not need to try to manipulate the request in other ways.

```
fetch("https://api.some-domain.com/...", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

My solutions have mostly used axios, since in the past I've found it to have better support for reading error response bodies. I've only needed to use basic code like this to send same site cross origin cookies to APIs:

```
const options = {
     url,
     method,
     headers: {
         accept: 'application/json',
     },
     withCredentials: true,
};
const response = await axios.request(options);
```

**SUMMARY**

I can verify that in a compliant same site setup with the right CORS permissions, you can send cookies from a web origin to a sibling API domain, and also from a sibling iframe to the same API. I have done quite a bit of work in this area, and tested your iframe scenario in all of the main browsers. Eg you can run my [Online SPA](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/), which uses API driven cookies. As a next step, see if any of this helps, and post back any results if the issue persists.

Comment: The rootcause was stupid. I should have added withCredentials to both POST And GET request. Unfortuantely I add it only into GET, and it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If you do use Chrome Browser, you should use it's tools to properly analyze what's happening with your request and how browser treats them. Of course I'm talking about it's **DevTools**. I think you already use "Network" tab  (but just in case I'm wrong, you can open them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), where you can see i.g. headers that were actually sent (and they might be not those you try to send), but maybe "Application" tab could be of additional help, because you can see there which cookies are actually saved, with wich parameters and for which sites.

Maybe it's not an exhaustive answer for your question, but I hope it will help you to figure out one yourself. At least I have a feeling, that I don't see the full picture of what's happening by you, and above is the way I would take to get better understanding. And with better understanding may come the proper solution